# GROUP_CONCAT in sub-query based on specified values

Tags: mysql, group-concat

**User Table:**

```
ID       InstructionSets
 1        123,124
```

**Instruction Set Table:**

```
ID       Name
 123      Learning SQL
 124      Learning More SQL
```

**Desired Query Result:**

```
UserID    SetID             SetNames
 1         123,124           Learning SQL,Learning More SQL
```

**Current SQL:**

```
SELECT U1.ID AS UserID, U1.InstructionSets AS SetID, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY FIELD(I1.ID, U1.InstructionSets))
    FROM Instructions I1
    WHERE I1.ID IN (U1.InstructionSets)
) AS SetName
FROM Users U1
WHERE `ID` = 1
```

**RESULT**

```
UserID   SetID             SetNames
 1        123,124           Learning SQL
```

As expected, if I remove the WHERE clause in the sub-query, all of the SetNames appear; but if I specify the required IDs, I only get the name associated with the first ID. Obviously, I also need to fetch the SetNames in the same order as the IDs. Hence ORDER BY in GROUP_CONCAT.

**Also:**

- Is there a better approach (other than storing the user instruction set assignments in a separate table — overkill for this application)? Couldn't see how to use JOIN in this
  situation.
- Is there a better title for this question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of IN use LIKE operator like this:

```
SELECT U1.ID AS UserID, U1.InstructionSets AS SetID, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY (I1.ID))
    FROM Instructions I1
    WHERE CONCAT(',', U1.InstructionSets, ',') LIKE concat('%,', I1.ID, ',%')
) AS SetName
FROM Users U1
WHERE `ID` = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sb4Tmv9Zwc7xqtS2Zv5SS4/2).
Results:

```
| UserID | SetID   | SetName                        |
| ------ | ------- | ------------------------------ |
| 1      | 123,124 | Learning SQL,Learning More SQL |
```

Comment: I received NULL in the field. Also, I'm assuming that it would be CONCAT(',', U1.InstructionSets, ','), no?

Comment: Right, give me a few mins.

Comment: I suspect the `name` values are not being ordered in `GROUP_CONCAT` with the `FIELD()` function; with the given example, the return from the `FIELD` function will be zero for every item.

Comment: @forpas: (Thank you for efforts. Greatly appreciated.) The latest version fetches the proper InstructionSet names but, as you noted in your second comment, the InstructionSet names are not in the proper order. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: @forpas: Correction: As "spencer7593" noted, the order is incorrect.

Comment: NOTE: The portion of the answer as posted "GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY (I1.ID))" only works when the fields are requested in ascending order, as was the case for my original example, however, spencer7593's solution "GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(I1.ID, U1.InstructionSets))" works in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `FIND_IN_SET()`. In this context, using `FIELD()` function doesn't make sense.

We can also use `FIND_IN_SET()` in the `WHERE` clause. (Function returns 0 when the string isn't found in the string list.)

e.g.

```
SELECT u.id               AS userid
     , u.instructionsets  AS setid
     , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(i.id, u.instructionsets))
           FROM `Instructions` i
          WHERE FIND_IN_SET(i.id, u.instructionsets))
       ) AS setname
 FROM `Users` u
WHERE u.id = 1
```

---

Storing comma separated lists is an *anti-pattern*; a separate table isn't overkill.

---

Assuming `id` is unique in `Users` table, we could do a join operation with a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT u.id                   AS userid
     , MIN(u.instructionsets) AS setid
     , GROUP_CONCAT(i.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(i.id, u.instructionsets))) AS setname
 FROM `Users` u
 LEFT
 JOIN `Instructions` i
   ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, u.instructionsets)
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```